# Array initialization with only one constructor call

Tags: c++, arrays

In cpp, is this or something equivalent possible?

```
Foo bar[23] = Foo();
```

EDIT:

The motivation for the question was that I think I saw somebody using this syntax

```
vtkSmartPointer<Foo> bar[23] = vtkSmartPointer<Foo>::New();
```

and wondered why it compiles and how many new objects are actually created...

Comment: What does it mean?  Are all `Foo bar[i]==f`?  Do they each have a new Foo()?  ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with this syntax, but if `Foo` has a non-trivial default
constructor,

```
Foo bar[23];
```

will call it for each member of the array.  More generally, you can also
write:

```
Foo bar[23] = { x, y, z... };
```

The compiler will try to convert each initializer (which can be an 
arbitrary expression) into a `Foo`, and use that to initialize the
element of the array.  If there are not enough initializer expressions,
then all of the following elements will be initialized with `Foo()`.

EDIT:

Since several comments asked for it: if Foo doesn't have a user defined
constructor, the situation changes (since calling the "constructor"
won't do anything).  In that case, the behavior of:

```
Foo bar[23];
```

depends on the variables lifetime: if it has static lifetime, it will be
zero initialized; otherwise, it won't be initialized at all.  In either
case, you can use aggregate initialization to force the initialization
you want:

```
Foo bar[23] = { { firstMember, secondMember... }, ... };
```

If there aren't enough initializers, the remaining elements are zero
initialized, so:

```
Foo bar[23] = {};
```

will zero initialize all of the members.

For completeness, I should point out that aggregate initialization
cannot be used for class members: the only ways you can initialize a C
style array member is by means of assignment to each element, in the
body of the constructor, or by copy initialization: define a static
`Foo` and initialize the member with it.

I should probably also point out that all of the above refers to C++03.
C++11 introduced an extended initialization syntax; in particular, you
can use something that looks like aggregate initialization for class
members as well.  (I think—I'm not too familiar with C++11, as not
all of my compilers support it yet.)

Comment: +1 a fine synopsis. To be really thorough, perhaps add something about the behaviour of POD structs here?

Comment: I agree with Karl: the behavior for types `Foo` that end up uninitialized could be a gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use an `std::vector`, you can use this:

```
std::vector<Foo> bar(23, Foo()); // initialize bar with 23 copies of Foo()
```

Comment: Or just `std::vector<Foo> bar(23)`, which initialized `bar` with 23 default-constructed `Foo` objects (in C++11; usually a slight optimization).

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an array using the following syntax:

```
struct Foo
{
};

Foo x[2] = {Foo(), Foo()};
//or
Foo y[] = {Foo(), Foo()};
```

In the latter case, the size of the array is deduced from the initialization.

Comment: Where do you see a constructor initializer list?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Foo bar[23] = { Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), /* ... 23 of them */ };
```

Comment: Not necessary, since that's what the compiler will do anyway.

Comment: Well, for default initialization, sure, but I'm assuming the OP was looking for more flexibility than that.